# Alternative definition of complex number, showing it is equivalent to the tradidional one.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-verification

The author of a book makes an alternative definition of the complex numbers, later he shows that this definition is equivalent to the ordinary definition where we define $i^2=-1$.

Here is his definition:

[image]

Here he shows that they are equivalent:

[image]

Now comes my questions:

1. Has he really shown that they are equivalent. It seems to me that maybe he has shown that starting with the ordered pair definition he gets the tradisional definition of $i^2=-1$. But isn't that only an implication and not an equivalence. Should he have also shown it the other way around, starting with the original definiton, and showed that it implies the ordered pair definition?
2. Why is it enough to show what he did. If I were asked to show it I would have thought that I must also show that both definitions are equivalent when you add or multiply. Why hasn't he showed that? Or has he showed that implicitly?

Comment: Some (easy) details are missing, showing that the mapping that takes $a+bi$ to $(a,b)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks! I will try to state it precisely is this what we have to show? 1. the function f(a+bi)=(a,b) is 1-1 and onto(this is trivial, nothing to show)?. 2. f((a+bi)+(c+di))=f(a+bi)+f(c+di)=(a,b)+(c,d). 3.f((a+bi)*(c+di))=f(a+bi)*f(c+di)=(a,b)*(c,d)?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Are that enough to show that they are equal?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much! I just have one more simple question, when I have showed that, it is not nececceary to do what he did in 1.28 and 1.29?

Comment: That's right, it is then implicit that for example the square of $(0,1)$ is $(-i,0)$. But obviously that is very much worth pointing out, it is a key fact. Another key bit of information is that the objects $(a,0)$ give us a subset of the complex numbers isomorphic to the reals.

Comment: The problem with starting out with the definition $i^2=-1$ is that you must assume there exists some value $i$ first. We are not yet guaranteed such an existence.

Answer (score -2):

They are the same thing, just written in an other way! Complex numbers in the plane can be represented as an ordered pair, and there they are homeomorphic to $R^2$. If in $R^2$ we define the addition and multiplication of two vectors, as in the definition given, than $R^2$ and complex numbers will be algebraically the same, so they would be equivalent.

P.S. the other way of the given proof is trivial: $i=0+1i=(0,1)$.

Comment: It seems like you used that i=(0,1) there? Isn't this something that should be proved if you go the other way? Also I don't doubht that they are equal. But it seems that algebraically they are handled very differently, so shouldn't it be proved that all operations will be the same when we use the different representations?, or has he proved that they will be?, that is what I do not understand.

Comment: i=(0,1) is given as a definition!

Comment: And algebraically they are identically, you can prove it by proving that the map $a+bi \to (a,b)$ is isomorphic.

Comment: $i$ and $(0,1)$ are just symbols, at the end of the day you just need an isomorphism between the symbols.

Comment: -> They are the same thing, just written in an other way!

Comment: Exactly.  This question is like, "Are $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ the same in intro. anlysis? My professor uses $\varepsilon$ in his notes but my textbook uses $\epsilon$."